# how to select column cells

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have written code for adding the value into cells ..LIKE A1,A2,A3, and so on code is

```
Sum = Abs(rangex1) + Abs(rangex2)

Debug.Print (Sum)

step_size = Sum / XDim

step_half = step_size / 2

start_point = rangex1 + step_half
Debug.Print (step_size)
Debug.Print (step_half)
Debug.Print (start_point)

For i = 1 To XDim

Range("A" & i) = start_point
start_point = start_point + step_size

Next i
```

now i want to add value into cells by column wise for example: 
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 and so on...
may i no how can i use the for loop

Comment: You need to provide more details. What evnvironment are you working in? Is it `VB.NET` or `VBA`? Where is the rest of the code? What is `Sum`, `rangex1`, `rangex2`, `step_size`, `XDim`, `start_point` etc and how are they declared? And what is the question? Please see the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Cells(r,c)` property. Where `r` is the Row number and `c` is the Column number

For example

`A1` is `Cells(1,1)`

`B1` is `Cells(1,2)` and so on...

So you can write a loop like this

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To 5 '<~~ A to E. Change as applicable
        .Cells(1, i).Value = "Blah Blah"
    Next
End With
```